# How to conduct the two sample test with extra data to eliminate between-subjects variability

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, genetics

I am stuck with the correlated and independent data combined in one study. Here's my dilemma:

Say X is a drug(explanatory variable) and Y is a gene expression(response variable).

Normally, you would give out drugs to a half of your group(randomly chosen) and placebo to the rest, measure the gene expression for each person in the group, and conduct the differential expression analysis between two conditions using a standard package such as deseq.

However, let's say between-subjects variability is huge, so you also measured the gene expression prior to taking the pill as well.  In other words, each subject has two data points(before and after the taking the pill).  How do you incorporate this information into the analysis? I tried to subtract the 'before' value from after 'value' for each patient, and conduct t-test on those statistics between conditions(drug & placebo), but I am not sure if I am doing it right.

I am curious if there is a standard, already established way to do this?
You can assume Y follows Poisson or negative binomial.

Answer (score 2):

You can enter the "before" value as a control variable in the model. It sounds like your DV is a count variable (you say it's Poisson distributed), so you'd want to run a Poisson regression model with your IV (whether or not they got the drug, coded as a dummy variable, e.g. 0 for no and 1 for yes) and the "before" value as predictors. This kind of model is sometimes called an [ANCOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_covariance). It allows you to measure the difference in "after" scores for the drug vs. no drug group after controlling for "before" scores.

Note that the model described above assumes that the relationship between "before" and "after" scores would be the same in both groups. In many cases, that assumption isn't reasonable. To relax it, also include the interaction between "before" and the drug dummy variable in the model (so you would have three predictors total).